# ListView disappears when populated using AsyncTask and launched from ExpandableListView ImageView click

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am launching a ListActivity as such from the getChildView method of an expandable list.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want see all vendors selling this item?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SellerListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("category", laptop);
                context.startActivity(intent); 

            }
    });
}
```

The ListAcitivity class onCreate looks as such:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seller_list);

    String[] from = { "name", "phone" };
    int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SellerListActivity.this, sellerList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);


    SellerListActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    /*Go and fetch the sellers*/
    new RetrieveContactsAll().execute();
}
```

RetrieveContactsAll is an AsyncTask with the below onPostExecute function

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> sellerList) {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the expandable list child I see that the list view is populated and shows momentarily before it disappears and is replaced by the expandable list.

Comment: Where are u setting data for the adapter In your async task i only see notifydatasetchanged call. where are you actually setting the data

Comment: I am modifying the sellerList array in the doBackground function. That list is used in the adapter. Do I need to set the adapter again?

Comment: Found out what was wrong, had a finish() in the doBackground call. Thanks.